# Configure browser to include meta tag with every response

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

Is there a way to configure a web browser to include a specific meta tag with every response that it gets? For example, the browser goes out to google.com, google sends a response, the browser receives this response but before rendering it, appends a meta tag within the head of the response.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, the solution was to create a custom browser plugin. For IE [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w?fid=1606392&df=10000&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4475707) explains exactly how to do just that.